# Find the Fourier Coefficients that minimize the error

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

[image]

I know that the coefficients that minimize the expression are the ones that make it's derivative 0. I have also expanded the whole expression and taken it's derivative, but still I can't figure out the coefficients. The solution must involve differentiating En. Any ideas?

Comment: Unless your instructor absolutely insist on finding the derivative etc., consider that the extremum of the function $px^2 + qx + r$ is at the point $x=-\frac{q}{2p}$ and the extremum is a  _minimum_ if $p > 0$. Now, note that $E_N$ is a _quadratic function_ of $b_n$ whose coefficients (corresponding to the $p, q, r$) are _integrals._  So, work out the integrals corresponding to $p$ and $q$ and the answer falls out immediately.

Comment: It is stated right there "by differentiating". It is supposed to be done by finding the derivative.

Comment: _"It is stated right there "by differentiating". It is supposed to be done by finding the derivative."_   Have you ever tried to find _where_ $px^2+qx+r, p > 0$, attains a minimum value by differentiating and setting the derivative to $0$ and then checking the second derivative, etc.?

Comment: In fact, an _exact_ duplicate.

Comment: It might be a duplicate but there is no helpful information in the other link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $1 \le k \le N$,
$$
\begin{align}
     \frac{\partial E_{N}}{\partial b_{k}} & = -\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}2\left[f(x)-\sum_{n=1}^{N}b_{n}\sin nx\right]\sin kx\,dx \\
   & = -2\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\sin kxdx+2b_{k}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin^{2}kx\,dx \\
   & = -2\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\sin kx dx +2b_{k}\pi.
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
   \frac{\partial E_{N}}{\partial b_{k}} = 0 \iff b_{k}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\sin kx dx.
$$
The second derivative matrix is diagonal and equal to $2\pi I$.